# need trick with object creator

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

This is my code:

```
public interface InterfaceA<J>{  
    // …
} 

public interface InterfaceB extends InterfaceA<String> {
    // …
} 

public interface InterfaceC extends InterfaceA<Long>{  
    // …
}

public class Creator<J, I extends InterfaceA<J>> {}

public abstract class Base<J, J1> implements InterfaceA<J> {    
    protected Creator<J, J1> creator;    

    protected Base() {
        creator=ObjectCreator.createCreator();
    }   
}

public class Extension1 extends Base<Integer> implements InterfaceB {
    // …
}

public class Extension2 extends Base<Double> implements InterfaceC {
    // …
}
```

I want `Extension1` to have `Creator<Integer, InterfaceB>` and `Extension2` to have `Creator<Double, interfaceC>`. See the pattern? `Creator<T1, T2>` where `T1` is the type of immediate parent and `T2` is the interface implemented by said class. Is there any way to do this? can anybody tell the code of `ObjectCreator.createCreator()`?

Right now my code looks like this:

```
public class ObjectCreator {
    public static <J, I extends InterfaceA<J>> Creator<J, I> createCreator() {
        return new Creator();
    }
}
```

I got errors all over my code. I'm really confused. What am I missing here?

Comment: At First is this code syntactically correct? because i think the few keywords are missing to compile the code.

Comment: Please check your code properly before uploading in SO. The Generics are not properly used. Line protected Creator<J, J1> creator;  doesnt make sense and code needs proper syntax.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that, must have deleted by mistake when editting to change all the "less than" for opening bracket

Comment: Use Ctrl-K / Cmd-K, or backticks to format names of classes instead of HTML escapes.

Comment: (Also, that's not the correct syntax for HTML escape codes.)

Comment: In fact, read this whole thing: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: If all you're doing is returning a raw `Creator()`, why all the crazy generics? As in, what type safety do you gain by this?

Comment: okay, thanks for the help editing my post. I don't understand, are there different kinds of type safety? I want type safety, that's all. perhaps I misunderstand your question, but I want checking so not all object can be passed, only objects of certain type.

Comment: If you're instantiating a raw `Creator`, casting it to `Creator<String, InterfaceA<String>>` is inherently **not** type safe in and of itself, and all the angle bracket nonsense is just lying to yourself. That is unless your Creator does some runtime type checks of objects it creates, in which case you should pass the `Class` object of that type to the Creator and use [`Class.cast()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast(java.lang.Object)) in its implementation. At which point the `Creator` won't have to be instantiated as a raw type.

Comment: Basically, raw types are bad, casting to raw types is bad, and if you can't make raw type cast warnings go away with type tokens and `Class.cast()`, then your code is not statically type safe. (It might be safe at runtime, in which case it's okay to use `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`.)

Answer (score 0):

There's a whole bunch of stuff you missed, a compiling version would look something like this:

```
package scratch;

interface InterfaceA<J> {
    // …
}

interface InterfaceB extends InterfaceA<String> {
    // …
}

interface InterfaceC extends InterfaceA<Long> {
    // …
}

class Creator<J, I extends InterfaceA<J>> {
}

abstract class Base<J, I extends InterfaceA<J>> {
    protected Creator<J, I> creator;

    protected Base(Class<J> jClass, Class<I> iClass) {
        creator = ObjectCreator.createCreator(jClass, iClass);
    }
}

class Extension1 extends Base<String, InterfaceB> implements InterfaceB {
    protected Extension1() {
        super(String.class, InterfaceB.class);
    }
}

class Extension2 extends Base<Long, InterfaceC> implements InterfaceC {
    protected Extension2() {
        super(Long.class, InterfaceC.class);
    }
}

class ObjectCreator {
    public static <J, I extends InterfaceA<J>> Creator<J, I>
    createCreator(Class<J> jClass, Class<I> iClass) {
        return new Creator();
    }
}
```

In no particular order of importance:

- When you have a class with a signature like `createCreator()` has, you need to pass `Class` objects as type tokens to it. The Java compiler can't infer the types based on the type of the variable you're assigning the return value to. Besides, you want them there anyway because of type erasure, otherwise you couldn't specialise the `Creator` based on the given types.

  - If you have `Base<J, I>` with two type parameters, extending classes should use both of those type parameters.
  - Your extension class signatures were odd. You can't have `class Extension1 extends Base<Integer, InterfaceA<String>>`, because you can't have a `Creator<Integer, InterfaceA<String>>`. Using explicit type tokens in `createCreator()` would have forced you to propagate this constraint everywhere it needs to be and made the error less mysterious. You can't really make `Base` independent of the constraint between the `J` and `I` type parameters.

Comment: actually I wish to avoid the using of .class as the parameter. So you're saying it's impossible to avoid .class to get what I want? Java just don't support this? yeah, type erasure is always a nuisance. will guys in sun create a solution so generics in java can be as powerful as in .net?

Comment: If you want this to be typesafe you can't avoid passing the type token around, it's as simple as that. In fact one of the main differences between Java and .NET generics is that in .NET, you can use the type parameter as a type token directly. Conversely you can do some of the things Java's generics "don't support" by using type tokens, `Class.cast()`, and other things at runtime.

Comment: As to the other question: they never will. The design of Java's generics was a conscious decision in favour of backwards compatibility over "power". The approach .NET took has a major disadvantage in that it makes it impossible to "retrofit" old APIs to use generics. This is why they had to create `System.Collections.Generic` instead of generifying `System.Collections`. One place where this shows is ASP.NET, where its repeater controls aren't generic and can never be made generic, and the only solution is an `.aspx` compiler hack, in v4.5, 8 years (!) after C# 2.0 and generics.